# Find GCD No Greater than $k$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have a set of integers $A = \{a:a > 0\}$ and an integer $k > 0$. I need to find $g$ of $A$, which is defined to be GCD of $A$ that is no greater than $k$. For example, if $A = \{20, 40, 60\}$ and $k = 10$, then $g$ should be $10$. Another example would be $A = \{36, 72,  90, 126\}$ and $k = 17$, in which case $g$ would be $9$.

Assume that there is already a function $f(a, b)$ that yields GCD of two positive integers $a$ and $b$. How would I go about writing an algorithm that finds $g$?

Comment: Are you interested in efficient algorithms or would any algorithm do? For instance if $k$ is small, then a simple algorithm would be to find the gcd of the set of numbers, say $g$ and find the largest number less than $k$ that divides $g$.

Comment: @Marvis While the examples I gave are very simple, in practice, $k$ will be fairly large, about 300, and $A$ will consist of large integers, e.g. 2517, 3120. The cardinality of $A$, however, will be pretty small, no greater than 10.

Comment: I consider $k \approx 300$ to be small. Hence, probably the simple algorithm would suffice. To get gcd of $n$ numbers, you need to call $f(f(f(\ldots (f(x_1,x_2),x_3), \ldots),x_{n-1}),x_n)$

Comment: @Marvis By finding the largest number less than k that divides g, are you suggesting trying to divide g by k, k - 1, k -2, etc?. Sorry - I'm a programmer with little math background.

Comment: Yes. I guess that would be a good way to go about. Will that be computationally expensive? For small $k$, I don't think so.

Comment: @Marvis Not really, as that would be just 300 iterations of a loop, but I was wondering if there is a systematic way of doing it.

Comment: You could start at $k$. Compute $f(k,g)$. If $f(k,g) = k$ you can stop, else $f(k,g)$ gives the lower bound for your next iteration. Repeat. The lower bound keeps increasing as you go through the loop. If nothing is hit till you reach the lower bound, then the answer is $1$.

Comment: @Marvis Thanks. That's certainly one way of doing it. Can you make a formal answer out of your comments? I'm sure it would get upvoted.